# Bachelor Thesis supervisor in a CV?

Tags: thesis, cv, supervision, projects

I am currently working in a research laboratory in a University under the leadership of one of the university professors. This professor is in charge of several students doing their Bachelor Thesis but sometimes he delegates the supervising work to me and then I supervise some students during the whole thesis.

I do not mind doing that, I liked. My question is if this task can be added in a CV or if it looks not professional. How can I add or explain it to add it in a CV? I am interested in add it as a personal skill (something like thesis supervising) and academic (supervisor of project X)

Comment: You could add a section entitled something along the lines of *student supervision* and list all the students you supervise, along with a few details (e.g., year, thesis title, ...), under this heading.

Comment: Should I name them even if I was not officially their supervisor? It is more an informal task

Comment: @user2768: "list all the students you supervise" - unlikely coincidences aside, the *names* of the students being supervised (rather than their thesis titles, or maybe just the number of theses supervised) is probably the least interesting information to provide to an external reader of a CV.

Comment: Arguably, listing undergraduate supervision isn't particularly interesting. But, I presume that @BrianJ. is an early stage researcher, thus, listing such information is useful to demonstrate abilities as a supervisor. I agree that names aren't particularly important, but they are useful if someone wants to look-up a particular thesis. Given that adding names takes up horizontal space, rather than vertical space, I'd be tempted to include (if I were listing them).

Comment: It depends if your CV is 'academic' or 'industrial'. They quite differ. For academic CD, you could list students' research projects (name the project, rather than the student: it is what matters) you at least supervize. You might want to indicate if you were the sole supervizor or not. For industrial CV, I'd be more concise and only mention that one of your task in your current job was student supervision. You might then show "how much" supervision you did.

Comment: The question is "Can I say I supervized a student even if it's not written on the front cover of his/her thesis?" As long as you indeed at least partially supervized students, my opinion is that you can list it. To know if you can list it, answer this question: are you confident making this statement in front of your current colleagues? You might want to keep some "proofs" of your supervision though (emails sent to students, colleagues who can attest this) if you think it's a critical point and that you're future employer is picky.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly add them to your CV. There's no general rule on how to write CVs so it's more or less personal preference. For an academic CV, teaching might be an important point, so I like to include "teaching experience" as a section but I prefer only mentioning "supervision of 5 bachelor theses and 2 diploma theses", otherwise it would get quite long.

In the end: if it makes sense and the information provided shows your qualification for the job then you should include it.

Comment: I know folks who have gotten turned down for jobs that require supervision experience even though they had such experience, so if that's part of the qualifications for the job you are applying for, definitely include this.